# Is OneToOne the right association for one-to-less-than-one in Doctrine?

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm

If I am relating two tables where each record in each table will not relate to more than one record in the other table, I assume that OneToOne is the right Doctrine association to use.  However, if the table that s not the owning side does not have a record for every record in the owning side table, is that really one-to-one?

For example, Table A may have 100 records and Table B may have 20 records.  The 20 records in Table B have a one-to-one relationship with 20 of the records in Table A, but another 80 records in Table A do not have a relationship with any records in Table B at all.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to your question will be sticking with One-to-One relationship. It doesn't matter all records in Table A are not relating with Table B. As long as you are sure that 1 record in Table B does not refer to more than 1 row in Table A, you can stick with 1-to-1. When it comes to mapping in Doctrine, in the Table B side use the 'mappedBy' attribute. And you may not necessarily include the 'inversedBy' attribute in Table A, as not all records in Table A relates with Table B.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!